# Simple drag and drop in windows phone 8

Tags: image, drag-and-drop, windows-phone-8

I'm making a solitaire card game for windows phone 8 and I want to drag and drop images. So far I can drag and move an image arround using this function but sometimes the image is behind some items

```
private void MouseMoving(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            Image realSender = (Image)sender;
            Canvas.SetZIndex(realSender, -2147483645); 
    }
```

Any ideas how to resolve this bug and how to drop the image in a canvas ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the MouseDragElementBehavior in Microsoft.Expression.Interactions assembly. It allows you to drag an object around and you can constrain it to be dragged inside its parent which might be a canvas.

The xaml looks like this:

```
<Image Height="110" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Assets/Tiles/IconicTileMediumLarge.png" Margin="254,90,95,407" MouseMove="MouseMoving">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <el:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="True"/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Image>
```